# Edit profiles on FOSUserBundle Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to make a panel for admin user to administrate users profiles. I mean, I got a table of users and Admin can edit their information chossing the user.
The problem is, that when im trying to edit some user profile, i can't save the changes and only allow me to change the logged user's profile.

### Thats my code :

```
 /**
 * Edit the user.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }
    /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);
    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }
    /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');
    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
        return $response;
    }
    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Profile/edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

 /**
 * Edit the user.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function editUserAction($id,Request $request)
{
    $user= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BackEndBundle:User')->findOneById($id);
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }
    /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);
    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }
    /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');
    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
        return $response;
    }
    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Profile/edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'title' => 'Edit User'
    ));
}


/**
 * Edit the user.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }
    /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);
    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }
    /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');
    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
        return $response;
    }
    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Profile/edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

---

Routing:

EDIT OWN PROFILE(LOGGED USER)

```
exchangeit_back_end_usuari_edit:
    path:     /edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit }
```

TABLE ADMIN

```
exchangeit_back_end_usuari_edit_taula:
    path:     /edit-tabla/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Profile:editUser }
```

EDIT :

SOLVED THE PROBLEM CREATING MY OWN FUNCTION.

```
    public function editUserAction($id,Request $request){
    $usuari = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BackEndBundle:User')->findOneById($id);
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($usuari)
        ->add('image', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Imatge','attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'),
                'label_attr'=> array('class' => 'label_text spaceTop')))
        ->add('dni', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Dni','attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'),
                'label_attr'=> array('class' => 'label_text spaceTop')))
        ->add('lastname', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Cognom','attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'),
                'label_attr'=> array('class' => 'label_text spaceTop')))          
        ->add('username', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom d\'usuari','attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'),
                'label_attr'=> array('class' => 'label_text spaceTop')))  
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('label' => 'Email','attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'),
                'label_attr'=> array('class' => 'label_text spaceTop')))    
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array('label' => 'Password','attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'),
                'label_attr'=> array('class' => 'label_text spaceTop')))    
        ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array('label' => 'Rol', 
        'attr' => ['class' => 'selectRol'],
        'required' => true, 'choices' => array("Traductor" => 'ROLE_TRANS',"Administrador" => 'ROLE_ADMIN', "Usuari" => 'ROLE_USER'), 'multiple' => true))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Editar Usuari',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-warning mt')))
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {            
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $password = $usuari->getPassword();
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $passwordEncrypt = $encoder->encodePassword($usuari, $password);
        $usuari->setPassword($passwordEncrypt);
        $em->persist($usuari);
        $em->flush();
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'notice',array(
                'type' => 'success',
                'msg' => 'S\'ha editat l\'usuari'
        ));
        return $this->redirect($this->generateurl('exchangeit_back_end_llistaUsuaris'));
    };

    return $this->render('BackEndBundle:Default:form.html.twig', array(
        'title' => 'Editar Usuari',
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an admin bundle to edit your users?

Comment: I'm new at symfony, i thought that i could admin roles and user's profile with FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Not really. Try easyadmin bundle: https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle

Comment: But with EasyAdmin, can i assign roles to users and restrict pages to this roles ?

Comment: No, it's for an administrator only. Or perhaps you can do it with sonata which is another admin bundle but more complex.

Comment: i would like to edit my code to works but if  i don't succeed i will try your bundle. Thanks.

Comment: Did you actually add this code to the controller in the FOSUserBundle folder ??    this is not the way to do this ! dont edit your vendor files ..

Comment: I solved the problem creating my own function to edit users using a table. And for edit user's profile i used the own method of FOSUserBundle.

Comment: UPDATED with my solution. Thanks all for help.